# shows "message":"404 Not Found", while using dingo to create api in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, dingo-api

I have configure dingo package in laravel 5.1 but while I try to access

http://localhost:8000/test

it is showing following error

```
{"message":"404 Not Found","status_code":404,"debug":{"line":161,"file":"C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException","trace":["#0 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(750): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection->match(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#1 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(659): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->findRoute(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#2 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#3 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Routing\\Adapter\\Laravel.php(81): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#4 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Routing\\Router.php(513): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Adapter\\Laravel->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), 'v1')","#5 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Request.php(126): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#6 [internal function]: Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#7 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#8 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#10 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#11 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#13 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#14 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#16 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#17 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#19 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#20 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#22 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#23 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#25 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#27 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#28 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Request.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))","#29 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Request.php(103): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))","#30 [internal function]: Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))","#31 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))","#33 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))","#34 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))","#35 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))","#36 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\public\\index.php(54): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))","#37 C:\\wamp64\\www\\second\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\wamp64\\\\www\\\\s...')","#38 {main}"]}}
```

I have following code in routes.php

```
<?php

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->get('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@index');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

While U check for api:route, it shows following following route:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the route cache `php artisan cache:clear`?

Answer (score 2):

**First:**
You need to run

```
php artisan api:cache
```

after adding or editing on your routes.php file. Dingo API get your routes from route cache. You can not define anonymous function on your route file. Dingo through an error while caching route. Please move your welcome view into a controller's method. Then run **php artisan api:cache**. I hope this will solve your problem. Additionally you can check second solution.

**Second:**

Dingo have a couple of configuration that need to be on your .env file.

```
API_PREFIX=api
```

Tells you that all of your api endpoint will be prefix by "api". So your api endpoint for test will be.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/test
```